# CSS Card Effect: Back face not showing on top of parent background

Tags: html, css, macos, google-chrome

I have an element with a black background color and 2 child elements with different background colors. They are set up to flip like a card, showing the back-face (second child div) when flipped. Works well on Chrome for Windows and Firefox for both Windows and OSX, but for some weird reason, on Chrome for OSX it does not show the back face when flipped, instead it shows the parent background color:

```css
.flipper{
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition:transform 0.5s ease-out;
  overflow: visible;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  position:relative;
  background:black;
}

.flipper.flipped {
  transform:rotate3d(0,1,0,180deg);
}


.face{
    position: absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:10px;
    right:10px;
    bottom:10px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 3px;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    overflow:hidden;

}

.front{
      transform: rotate3d(0,0,0,0deg);
}

.back{
      transform: rotate3d(0,1,0,180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flipper">

<div class="front face" style="background:red;">
<button onclick='$(".flipper").toggleClass("flipped")'> FLIP TO BACK
</button></div>

<div  class="back face" style="background:blue;">
<button onclick='$(".flipper").toggleClass("flipped")'> FLIP TO FRONT
</button></div>
</div>
```

You might only be able to view this error on chrome on a mac.

Any ideas how to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use `transform: translateZ(0);` to the content in elements you're flipping.

```css
.flipper{
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition:transform 0.5s ease-out;
  overflow: visible;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  position:relative;
  background:black;
}

.flipper.flipped {
  transform:rotate3d(0,1,0,180deg);
}


.face{
    position: absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:10px;
    right:10px;
    bottom:10px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 3px;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    overflow:hidden;

}

.front{
      transform: rotate3d(0,0,0,0deg);
}

.back{
      transform: rotate3d(0,1,0,180deg);
}

button {
  transform: translateZ(0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flipper">

<div class="front face" style="background:red;">
<button onclick='$(".flipper").toggleClass("flipped")'> FLIP TO BACK
</button></div>

<div  class="back face" style="background:blue;">
<button onclick='$(".flipper").toggleClass("flipped")'> FLIP TO FRONT
</button></div>
</div>
```